# python re.search quantifier

Tags: python, regex, search

I have this:-

```
re.search("^[47]{2:}$", '447447')
```

... and was expecting it to return True.
But somehow it does not.

How come?
My understanding is that it was suppose to match any number which has any combination of 4 or 7, with at least 2 digits.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should probably be `"^[47]{2,}$"`.

I visit the [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) page quite often, because I find it hard to remember all of the little tricks for building regexes.

Comment: ahhh Thx for the link. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `{m,n}` where *n* could be omitted.

Fix:

```
re.search("^[47]{2,}$", '447447')
```

See RegEx syntax: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Laurent, I think you mean that *n* can be omitted : )  Of course, *m* can be omitted too, but OP is asking about at least 2 chars ...

Comment: Yes it's a little mistake. I fixed that.